# Error in struct variable data when declaring it in the struct definition

Tags: c++

In this instance, the program works just as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
struct candyBar
{
    char brandName[20];
    double weight;
    int calories;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    candyBar snack = { "Mocha Much", 2.3, 350 };
    cout << snack.brandName << "\t" << snack.weight << "\t" << snack.calories << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But in this iteration, when declaring the variable *snack* just after defining the struct *candyBar*, the program shows the following warnings:

- (Line 13): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'char', possible loss of data
- (Line 13): warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'int' to 'char'
- (Line 13): warning C4309: 'initializing': truncation of constant value

The program outputs the correct values for the members *brandName* and *weight*, but changes the value of *calories*, 350, to 94. Why does this happen?

```
#include <iostream>
struct candyBar
{
    char brandName[20];
    double weight;
    int calories;
} snack;

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    snack = { "Mocha Much", 2.3, 350 };
    cout << snack.brandName << "\t" << snack.weight << "\t" << snack.calories << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fot the fiest program, [I got no error](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vVTjiSLXzo7Ntklg). For the second program, [I got some error](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/I1uTtCjwZKJ3CZeV) at the assignment,

Comment: @molbdnilo That should be fine. It is an aggregate.

Comment: Both look fine to me. I suspect a compiler bug. What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: It looks like your compiler doesn't support C++11.

Comment: Please post your compiler and the compiler version. And don't use `char[]`. Use `std::string`.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015